# How to duplicate a live 3D object in another place in a scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I have built a game object in Unity that updates its appearance every time the user touches it in VR (collision). What I want is to show the replica of that object in another place in the scene so that whenever the user touches the first object, I see the second object changing in appearance as well. Is there a faster way of doing this without creating a copy of that object in the scene beforehand and changing it every time a change happens in the first object. I suppose I'm asking if Unity has a way for me to show duplicate copies of a game object in a scene without having to create them in the scene beforehand.

Comment: You could change the shader you're rendering with to make an extra pass (or set of passes) with the vertex positions changed to suit your needs. This will only work if the original object is visible onscreen and if you don't need collision on the clone. If that's not good enough, copying the gameobject and altering it at the same time as the first is altered is about as fast as it can get.

Comment: "without having to create them in the scene beforehand" -> Well, you could also use a prefab and instantiate the objects via script.That way, you only need to change the prefab and it will reflect on both object, but it's not so different for what you are already doing.